# AutoLayout: Vertical to horizontal with no explicit sizes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I am interesting in accomplishing something of this kind, using  preferably only AutoLayout and no code:

[image: Demo 1]

Here are the constraints, that I need to maintain:

- No explicit view sizes, as both iPhone and iPad should be supported.
- View 1 maintains its square aspect ratio.
- View 2 takes all the remaining space (vertical or horizontal) and resizes its subviews.
- On rotation, change from vertical alignment to horizontal.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how something like this can be accomplished. AutoLayout seems a bit confusing for this kind of task.

Thanks a lot!

P.S. - As a more complicated follow-up, do you think something like this is achievable? I am a bit skeptical.

[image: Demo 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of this is definitely possible with Auto Layout.  It will just require some code!

To address each bullet point:

- This is what AutoLayout is all about.  Depending on your implementation, you should actually have a difficult time NOT making it work on both the iPad and iPhone.
- No problem

  ```
  [view1 addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
  ```
- Sure can

  ```
  UIView *view1;
  UIView *view2;
  UIView *superview;
  NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"border":@(VIEW1_BORDER)};
  NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view1,view2);
  UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation];
  if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)) {
      [superview addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[view1]-(border)-[view2]|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
      [superview addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[view2]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
  } else {
      [superview addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[view1]-(border)-[view2]|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
      [superview addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[view2]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
  }
  ```
- Implement the UIViewController *willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:* method and use the same code from above.  Just be sure to remove any previously added constraints before adding the new ones to avoid conflicting constraints. **UPDATE:** Since *willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:* is deprecated in iOS 8, you could observe the default NSNotificationCenter for 
  UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification and 
  UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification
  notifications to handle orientation changes.

Using three views would be nearly exact same code as above.

Comment: What you're doing by formatting the border into the visual format language string is what the `metrics` dictionary is for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and example code. So point here, basically, would be to define 2 different sets of constraints programmatically - one for horizontal and one for vertical layout? I was hoping this could be achieved only by using Interface Builder and only with one set of constraints. Looking at it now, I think it might be much more intuitive this way. I will wait few more days to see if there are any more responses, then mark it as accepted. Thanks again!

Comment: I would say it will be much easier, maybe even a requirement, to do this in code.  In your 2 view scenario, if view2 always remained below view1 then you could do all of this in IB.  Since view2 moves to the right side of view1 in landscape mode different constraints need to be used for the two orientations.  I think IB+AutoLayout is great when you only need to worry about resizing views, not so great when you also need a dynamic layout.